# What is the best way to process a large list of Domain Objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What is the best way to process a large list of Domain Objects?
For example, I have 'Users' and 'Book' domains, and there is a permission READ on Book object.
When I'm adding a new Book, I'd like to set READ permission to all users for this Book.
At first was a code:

```
def users = Users.findAll{ ... }
users.each { addPermission(book, it, READ) }
```

I'm using Spring Security Core and ACL plugin.
But now, I think it is not best way to load 10000 Users Objects to memory.
I gonna use the SCROLL method with maxResults(???) from Criteria.
So my question is What the best way? How to determinate the best number of MaxResults?

Comment: I guess you have a good reason for doing this but can't you solve it by creating add "BookGroup" where the book belongs and then give Users right to read all books in the "BookGroup"? Seems kind of overkill to use findAll but I don't know your situation in detail.

Comment: I'm using Spring Security ACL plugin. The Acl_entry table is responsible to keep all permissions. Your suggestion is good if I have only one permission - READ. But if we have WRITE, CREATE, DELETE ....

Comment: There are always some hurdles to overcome, if it was easy everyone would be developing systems.

If you're using spring security can't you control who can do what with roles?

Comment: Marco, I understand you to try to resolve it with OOP (adding new classes). But I have to call addPermission(book, it, READ) in same way. So my question is not how to change my model. I need to process a  large list only.

Comment: Alright, got it. I understand better where you're coming from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more of Grails way to do this would be to use the batch processing. Try the example given below:
**EDIT** : Improved answer. Now, using pagination based batch processing.

```
             def noOfObjectsTobeProcessedAtAtime=1000//Step or pagination size...

    List offsetMaxMapList = (0..User.count()-1).step(noOfObjectsTobeProcessedAtAtime).collect{[max:noOfObjectsTobeProcessedAtAtime,offset:it]}
    offsetMaxMapList.each{offsetMaxMap->
        addPermissionToUserInBatch(params)  

    }

    def addPermissionToUserInBatch(params){
        def batch = []
                def session
                def users = Users.createCriteria().list(params){}

                users.eachWithIndex { user, index ->
                    batch << user

                    if (batch.size() >= batchSize) {
                        User.withTransaction {
                            batch.each {User userObject ->
                             addPermission(book, userObject, READ)
                                }
                        }
                        batch.clear()

                    } else if (batch.size() < batchSize && (users.size() - index - 1) == 0) {
                        User.withTransaction {
                            batch.each {User userObject ->
                                 addPermission(book, userObject, READ)
                                }
                        }
                        batch.clear()
                    }
                    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    session.clear()
                }

    }
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I guess you want to control the size of the first-level cache. [see Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) But **def users = Users.findAll{ ... }** gets all Users in cache, isn't it?

Comment: @AndriiOlenchenko: Yes, you are right.I have made edits to my answer. Now, It will not load all objects at time. I know it will use more no. quires to load user objects

Comment: ok. but I think I can retrieve a batch of users to avoid sql request for each user.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I would do a bulk update.  ExecuteUpdate allows you to do such a thing and its much more performant.  Look at this example and customize it to your need.

```
def updatedRecords = User.executeUpdate("update User set permission = 'READ' where somecriteriaOrNot ")
```

Comment: This way is not applicable with using Spring Security ACL plugin, because the Acl_entry table keeps all permissions. I have to call addPermission(book, it, READ). Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I'd like to summarize. I hope ti will be a TEMPLATE to me.

```
def dc = new DetachedCriteria(Users).build{
    //some conditions of criteria 
}
def count = dc.count()

// Optional:            
// dc = dc.build{
//     projections { property('username') }
// }

def batchSize = 50 // Hibernate Doc recommends 10..50
0.step(count, batchSize){ offset-> 
    dc.list(offset:offset, max:batchSize).each{
       // doSmthWithTransaction(it)
    }
    //clear the first-level cache
    //def hiberSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() 
    //hiberSession.clear()
    // or
    Users.withSession { session -> session.clear() }
}
```

P.S. I don't use Transaction here since I use it on the doSmthWithTransaction method